# APK file still working without .apk extension?

Tags: android, file, apk

Today I noticed that when I export my app in Eclipse, I get an extensionless file. I didn't notice this in the past so I uploaded this file to Google Play as the APK file for my app. When I saw the file is extensionless today I tried installing it on my phone, which didn't work until I added the .apk extension manually. The weird thing is that the extensionless file that I uploaded to Google Play apparently was working, at least for some users. I manually added the .apk and re-uploaded the APK file to Google Play now, but how is it possible that it was working for these people even though it was missing the right extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play doesn't care what you named the APK when you upload it, since it will just throw away your filename anyway; uploaded apps get renamed to, e.g. `com.example.myapp.apk`.